# Is there a way to change background image after animation is done?

Tags: css, animation

I want to create a CSS animation where an image slides from the left side of the screen to the right side, but I have 5 images that should alternate. So first, image1 slides from left to right, then image2 follows, then image3, etc.. And finally when image5 is done, animation should go back to image1 and it should keep looping like that infinitely. Any way to achieve this in CSS?

Comment: You can achieve it using Bootstrap.  See w3schools tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h

Comment: Just see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate each image separately, but using the same animation.  Each image can then be `delay`ed by a different amount like:

```html
<div class = "slider" style = "--delay:0s"><img src = "1.jpg" /></div>
<div class = "slider" style = "--delay:1s"><img src = "1.jpg" /></div>
<div class = "slider" style = "--delay:2s"><img src = "1.jpg" /></div>
<div class = "slider" style = "--delay:3s"><img src = "1.jpg" /></div>
<div class = "slider" style = "--delay:4s"><img src = "1.jpg" /></div>
```

```css
.slider{
    animation-name: slideLR;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-delay: var(--delay, 0s);
}

@keyframes slideLR{
    from{ /* your initial state before sliding in */ }
    to{ /* your end state after sliding */ }
}
```

There are other properties like `animation-iteration-count` and `animation-fill-mode` that you'll have to use to get the looping working.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort of marquee but with images not text.

One (simplistic) way of doing this which makes it easy to alter the number of images without having to redo any calculations is to have two sets of the five imgs in one container. Translate it just 50% on each animation and it will go back to the inital position, but without any jerkiness because the second half is showing underneath, and that starts with the first img too.

This means you don't have to worry about fill mode or delay times.

This snippet has the number of imgs and their desired width set as CSS variables to make it easier to change them.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
div {
  --n: 5; /* number of images */
  --w: 25vw; /* width of an image */
  width: calc(var(--n) * var(--w) * 2);
  animation: animate 10s infinite linear;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  @keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  }
img {
  width: var(--w);
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1004/300/200"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1005/300/200"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/300/200"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1002/300/200"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/300/200"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1004/300/200"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1005/300/200"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/300/200"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1002/300/200"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/300/200"/>
</div>
```